# Cant see text when trying to reset root password

Tags: passwords, grub, reset

So I am trying to change the root password by altering the text in the GRUB menu edit mode, and the white circular outline for the Kali logo on the default background is PERFECTLY covering the string of text I have to make the edits in.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can still change the password in this scenario? I've tried guessing it but am coming up with nothing, even though I somehow remember the Encrypted LVM password..

Any help would be hugely appreciated, as I really don't want to have to wipe and re-do the drive encryption process. [Grub Menu - text string hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB2XD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the newline between `search` and `else` or delete the first `echo` line.
This should be sufficient to edit the kernel parameters and boot with these settings.

Comment: Wow. Sometimes it's the simplest of solutions that are the hardest to think of. Thank you very much!